# Split One Column into Two Columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet of over 1,000 contacts where the contact names are in one column, "First Name Last Name". Is there a way I can create a new column with just the last names so that I have a column for "First Name" and for "Last Name"?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A; " "))
```